# How to create Table using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

We are planning to migrate our pdf generation utilities from iText to PDFBox (Due to licensing issues in iText).  With some effort, I was able to write and position text, draw lines etc. But creating Tables with text embedded in Table cells is a challenge, I went through the documentation, examples, Google, Stackoverflow couldn't find a thing. Was wondering if PDFBox provides native support for creating Tables with embedded text. My last resort would be to use this link https://github.com/eduardohl/Paginated-PDFBox-Table-Sample

Comment: As far as document creation is concerned, PDFBox mainly is an equivalent to the low level API of iText. What you are missing is something replacing iText's high level API on top of that. I'm not aware of something like that available to the public.

Comment: Yeah, you nailed it. High level API for PDFBox for creating all these tables is what is missing. A lot of dev community is migrating from iText to other open source pdf libraries and I am sure someone will have an elegant solution.

Comment: Here's another: https://github.com/dhorions/boxable

Comment: And another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871879/apache-pdfbox-java-library-is-there-an-api-for-creating-tables

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm afraid all those samples IMO meely are proofs of concept, probably of use in limited use cases but by far not for generic use. PDFBox has its strengths, e.g. a quite versatile content extraction framework and a content rendering capability, but the absence a proper layouting API  is a serious weakness.

Comment: I know... I just don't want to create another iText. We're not the Samwer brothers. But I'll write something about that topic on the dev list tonight.

Comment: Thanks Tilman for the suggestions. I'll go through them and update my comments here. iText is an awesome library but their licensing really sucks. I myself am writing a lot of wrappers around pdfbox, when time permits, I'll publish the same.

Comment: I've posted my thoughts not in the dev list but in a JIRA issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2618

Comment: @Anil `I am sure someone will have an elegant solution` 7 years later and we still don't have that elegant solution

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to the links provided by Tilman. Using the boxable API (https://github.com/dhorions/boxable) I was able to create the table I wanted to. Just an FYI I wanted to create the table with variable number of cells. For example row 1 would have 2 cells, row 2 could have 5 cells and row 3 could have just 3 cells. I was able to do with ease. I followed Example1.java in the link mentioned above.

Comment: I couldnt find Example1.java you mentioned in your answer. WIll you please paste your code or Example1.java.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik: perhaps this [test](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/blob/master/src/test/java/be/quodlibet/boxable/TableTest.java) may help you.

Answer (score 116):

Since I also needed table drawing functionality for a side project, I implemented a small "table drawer" library myself, which I uploaded to [github](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable).

In order to produce such a table – for instance – ... 
[image]

... you would need [this code](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vandeseer/integrationtest/ExcelLikeExampleTest.java).
In the same file you find the code for that table as well:

[image]

The current "feature list" includes:

- set font and font size on table level as well as on cell level
- define single cells with bottom-, top-, left- and right-border width separately
- define the background color on row or cell level
- define padding (top, bottom, left, right) on cell level
- define border color (on table, row or cell level)
- specify text alignment (vertical and horizontal)
- cell spanning and row spanning
- text wrapping and line spacing

Also it should not be too hard to add missing stuff like having different border colors for borders on top, bottom, left and right-borders, if needed.

Comment: Tried to give this a shot.. are you missing a class `AWTColor` in the source?

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for your feedback! :) Obviously I didn't carefully check the last pull request. Please git pull again and it should be working now.

Comment: what about pagination?

Comment: You mean a table spanning over several pages? If so, have a look at this code which produces a table over three pages: https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vandeseer/integrationtest/TableOverSeveralPagesTest.java

Comment: @philonous does it support adding multiple tables one after another over several pages?

Comment: Well, if you want to draw a table over multiple pages, you can find an example here: [TableOverSeveralPagesTest.java](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vandeseer/integrationtest/TableOverSeveralPagesTest.java)

Comment: @philonous example shows only 1 table which is drawn over several pages..My use case is to have different tables which are next to each other & they could span across multiple pages

Comment: I think you would need to do at least some calculations yourself: You would need to keep track of the point where the next table should start to be drawn if another one just has finished. That shouldn't be too hard though.

Comment: @philonous do you happen to have example of it?I tried but seems like pagination is not happening properly with multiple tables

Comment: I don't have one yet, but just open an issue (tagged as question) on github and we can continue there.

Answer (score 0):

**This example code works for me. I think this would be helpful to you**

```
public static void creteTablePdf() throws IOException {
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);

    int pageWidth = (int)page.getTrimBox().getWidth(); //get width of the page
    int pageHeight = (int)page.getTrimBox().getHeight(); //get height of the page

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,page);
    contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    contentStream.setLineWidth(1);

    int initX = 50;
    int initY = pageHeight-50;
    int cellHeight = 20;
    int cellWidth = 100;

    int colCount = 3;
    int rowCount = 3;

    for(int i = 1; i<=rowCount;i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<=colCount;j++){
            if(j == 2){
                contentStream.addRect(initX,initY,cellWidth+30,-cellHeight);

                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(initX+30,initY-cellHeight+10);
                contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN,10);
                contentStream.showText("Dinuka");
                contentStream.endText();

                initX+=cellWidth+30;
            }else{
                contentStream.addRect(initX,initY,cellWidth,-cellHeight);

                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(initX+10,initY-cellHeight+10);
                contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN,10);
                contentStream.showText("Dinuka");
                contentStream.endText();

                initX+=cellWidth;
            }
        }
        initX = 50;
        initY -=cellHeight;
    }

    contentStream.stroke();
    contentStream.close();


    document.save("C:\\table.pdf");
    document.close();
    System.out.println("table pdf created");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To Create Table in PDFBOX using `RowBuilder`, you can add multiple rows like this:

- Add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
    <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
private void writeEndOfStatement(PDDocument pdf) {
    try {

        //Yaxis -------------
        float tempYaxis = Yaxis-30f;
        float tempXaxis = 15f;
        if (tempYaxis < (endOfPageYaxis + 5f)) {
            PDPage pg = Page.getpage(pdf);
            pdf.addPage(pg);
            tempYaxis = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY() - 110f;
            int page1 = pdf.getNumberOfPages() - 1;
            page = pdf.getPage(page1);
        }

        TableBuilder msgTableBuilder = Table.builder().fontSize(8).addColumnsOfWidth(tableWidth);

        //Data Row------------------------
        RowBuilder dataRowBuilder = Row.builder();
        dataRowBuilder
        .add(TextCell.builder().text("****End of Statement****" ).borderWidth(1).borderColor(Color.WHITE).backgroundColor(Color.white).fontSize(subHeading)
                .borderColorBottom(Color.WHITE).font(font).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build());

        msgTableBuilder.addRow(dataRowBuilder.build());



        //Draw Table  ----------- 
        Table transTable = msgTableBuilder.fontSize(fontSize).font(pdfFont)
                .horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY).build();
        float tempY = tempYaxis - 20f;
        // PDPage (Page.getpage(pdf)) = getnewPag(pdf, contentStream);
        TableDrawer tableDrawer = TableDrawer.builder().table(transTable).startX(tempXaxis)
                .startY(tempY).endY(50F) // note: if not set, table is
                // drawn over the
                // end of the page
                .build();
        tableDrawer.compress(true);

        tableDrawer.draw(() -> pdf, () -> (Page.getpage(pdf)), 102f);
        Yaxis = tableDrawer.getFinalY();
        int currentPage = pdf.getNumberOfPages() - 1;
        page = pdf.getPage(currentPage);
        System.out.println("Table End END OF THE Statements "+Yaxis);       
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {


    }       
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.