# How to generate Pdf invoice using Apache PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I have a requirement in my project to generate an invoice with the help of Apache pdfbox api.As of now I could insert images,text in the generated pdf but finding difficulty in generating tables.I couldn't find even a single example template.If anybody has please provide a link.

Note:I don't have to use iText

Thanx in Advance

Comment: https://github.com/dhorions/boxable

Comment: Thank you very much @TilmanHausherr , I will look into it.:-)

Answer (score 1):

This question can be a duplicate to [How to create Table using Apache PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059563/how-to-create-table-using-apache-pdfbox). But, I found two solutions which are build on Apache PDFBox.

- [easytable](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable), I used this to create tables, it has some good features like table extends into new page when reaches the bottom of current page. But I found difficulty in adding both text & image into same cell, multi styles texts into same cell. If any of these are your requirements better check for alternatives.
- [boxable](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/), Not much familiar with this, but heard that it has some nice features like converting csv data into table directly.

Comment: I think "multi styles texts in same cell" is possible as stated in the README.md: https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable#paragraph-cells