# What do you call the process of exporting information and data to a PDF document template?

Tags: java, pdf

I want to create a program in Java where the student information will be embedded to a specific template and generated into a PDF. The PDF may contain tables, image, and text.

I just want to know this technique? Here is a sample output below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

I tried looking for the term, and I was not able to find it. I am curious about it since I saw the operator in my cashier where they used a Java program that can generate the PDF that contains the student information from a database and print it.

Comment: That is a document template. Which you said in your question. For [example `PDFTemplateBuilder`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.4/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/digitalsignature/visible/PDFTemplateBuilder.html).

Comment: In the olden days this used to be called Mail-merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few useful library for generating PDF document in Java,

I suggest you to look at this library : [Apache PdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

also you can check this question for creating table:

[Creating table in pdf box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059563/how-to-create-table-using-apache-pdfbox)